# Load entire page into modal (Angular Bootstrap)

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to load a modal in my page, but when I load the page, I cannot load the "modal.html", instead, appears an exactly copy of the page in the modal.

I have the **MainController** with ui.bootstrap correctly injected and this function:

```
$scope.loadEditForm = function () {
   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalController',
      });
  };
```

**modal.html** which it is in the same directory of the controller.

```
<div class="modal-header">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

**main.html** page where I have the button to call the function:

```
<button ng-click="loadEditForm()">Edit Form</button>
```

And the **ModalController**:

```
angular.module('ModalController', []).controller('ModalController', function($scope, $http) {
});
```

So the problem is that when I click the button, the modal window appear with the same content of my "main.html", but there is nothing about my "modal.html"

If someone can help me I will be very grateful.

Thank you!

**Edited:**

When I click the button, in the console appears the following:

[Web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyGMB.png)

Comment: Do you have errors in the console ?

Comment: @AbbéRésina I have edited my post, with the error in the console. It is like the entire web is being loaded again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was in the path, I changed by:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
    templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
    controller: 'ModalController',
  });
```

Changing the modal.html to my "views" folder.